# Disable cache for specific RUN commands

Tags: docker

I have a few `RUN` commands in my Dockerfile that I would like to run with `-no-cache` each time I build a Docker image.

I understand the `docker build --no-cache` will disable caching for the entire Dockerfile.

Is it possible to disable cache for a specific RUN command?

Comment: Once you disable the cache for a single command, if the result doesn't match past cached run, you'd need to rebuild all remaining steps. Is that your goal, or do you hope to only rebuild a single layer and somehow inject that into where prior cached data was stored?

Comment: I was hoping to rebuild specific layers, for example a "git pull" command. 
Right now the "git pull" command will be cached, even though the repo is updated.

Comment: It's easy enough to force a pull by passing an unused argument. But the result of that cached entry being rebuilt is that all following layers will need a rebuild. See [my answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37798643/596285) for an example.

Comment: If looking to invalidate the cache when a git remote has changed take a look at: [How to prevent Dockerfile caching git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278224/2907791). All credit to [@anq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243335/anq) for the linked answer.

Answer (score 180):

There's always an option to insert some meaningless and cheap-to-run command before the region you want to disable cache for.

As proposed in [this issue comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996#issuecomment-185872769), one can add a build argument block (name can be arbitrary):

```
ARG CACHEBUST=1
```

before such region, and modify its value each run by adding `--build-arg CACHEBUST=$(date +%s)` as a `docker build` argument (value can also be arbitrary, here it is current datetime, to ensure its uniqueness across runs).

This will, of course, disable cache for all following blocks too, as hash sum of the intermediate image will be different, which makes truly selective cache disabling a non-trivial problem, taking into account how docker currently works.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, just got `---> Using cache` under my ``ARG CACHEBUST=1` line... (and yes I did do `--build-arg CACHEBUST=$(date +%s)` in my docker command)

Comment: Does not work for me either, maybe it is platform dependent. I would have expected any ARG change to invalidate the cache.

Comment: You have to add `RUN echo "$CACHEBUST"` as just using `ARG` will not invalidate the cache

Comment: This answer solved my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709147/run-npm-update-in-docker-without-using-the-cache-on-that-specific-update/63737657#63737657

Comment: Confirm working as of Podman `3.2.2` and Docker `20.10.6`. Side note: please do not assign the default value as in `ARG CACHEBUST=1`, instead just write `ARG CACHEBUST`. The difference is that in later case, may you forget to pass the `--build-arg`, you'll get a warning `WARN[0000] missing "CACHEBUST" build argument. […]` At least Podman behaves this way.

Comment: It is also possible to define a label instead of the echo, i.e. `LABEL cachebust=$CACHEBUST`. Better choices could be of course `buildDate` or `buildNumber` or something else providing valuable meta data.

Comment: To summarize, the build command  assigned a variable value to CACHBUST ( --build-arg CACHEBUST="{{ date_cmd_results.stdout }}") . In the dockerfile, before the RUN git clone... command, you execute "ARG CACHEBUST=1
RUN echo "$CACHEBUST" 
" ? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Working for me in Podman 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. I used just `ARG CACHEBUST` with no default value but of course what matters either way is injecting a random one on the build command line.

Answer (score 81):

Use

```
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
```

before the RUN line you want to always run.  This works because ADD will always fetch the file/URL and the above URL generates random data on each request, Docker then compares the result to see if it can use the cache.

I have also tested this and works nicely since it does not require any additional Docker command line arguments and also works from a Docker-compose.yaml file :)

Comment: whats going to happen if random.org decides to change that endpoint? how would you control that behaviour?

Comment: @AndresLeonRangel Admittedly this is not a Docker feature but kind of a hack using Docker syntax and well known web service that has been around for 20+ years, however you are right in saying them may deprecate that endpoint, in fact looking at their docs now I can't even find the "randbyte" endpoint and they have a new API currently in beta.  You can either 1) continue to use this endpoint until it fails, 2) use their new endpoint (until it fails) or 3) write your own random endpoint in which case you are in full control :)

Comment: This failed some times... when site is down!!!  I think it's not perfect solution for this. 

ADD failed: failed to GET https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h with status 503 Service Unavailable: <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: random.org has added DDOS protection which breaks this solution now

Comment: It doesn't work and given addess returns 503. If you don't want to block your pipelines do not use this solution

Comment: @OlegI The solution does work, as Brad has mentioned random.org have added DDOS protection so using that URL for this solution is probably now not viable, however writing your own simple endpoint that returns a series of random bytes is trivial and could be hosted on your build server guaranteeing that it works

Comment: This is so smart. In my case I'm installing a bunch of sw from a rolling release repository. By just downloading the db file using ADD first I get the install step to re-run automatically as soon as there are newer packages to install and cache the steps automatically when the versions are the same. Awsome! :)

Comment: Too funny, everyone is using this as solution and it becomes DDOS.

Comment: not sure why noone highlighted yet, but this does add a layer with a useless `skipcache` file. using `ARG CACHEBUST` + `RUN echo $CACHEBUST` does not

Comment: Does it work before a COPY command ?

Comment: why don't people use a local source of randomness like `/dev/urandom` ???

Comment: @jaksco I thought same initially, but it fails with "failed to compute cache key /dev/urandom not found" - urandom is an endless stream which on its own would ADD forever - I would not have expected the "not found" error though

Comment: We finally killed it. Alternative: http://www.randomnumberapi.com/api/v1.0/random?min=100&max=1000&count=5

Comment: @steve you need to mount it first  `-v /dev/urandom:/dev/random`

Comment: Adding such an external dependency you do not control is bad. If you deem it acceptable, you deserve anything that happens to you due to that. Its unavailability causing builds to break? Unexpected large responses bloating the image? Responses containing malicious code that becomes a part of an exploit, or at least triggering alerts in image security scanners? Everything.

Answer (score 34):

If your goal is to include the latest code from Github (or similar), one can use the Github API (or equivalent) to fetch information about the latest commit using an `ADD` command.
`docker build` will always fetch an URL from an `ADD` command, and if the response is different from the one received last time `docker build` ran, it will not use the subsequent cached layers.

eg.

```
ADD "https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo_name/commits?per_page=1" latest_commit
RUN curl -sLO "https://github.com/username/repo_name/archive/main.zip" && unzip main.zip
```

Comment: This is great. When the code changed, my git clone and tests run; when the code has not changed, cached values are used. Perfection.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, very clean and simple, just include the `ADD` step before whatever you currently do to install the package. Please upvote this answer to raise attention to it.

Comment: One note to add is that it works only for public repositories.

Answer (score 18):

Building on @Vladislav’s solution [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134713/disable-cache-for-specific-run-commands#49772666) I used in my Dockerfile

```
ARG CACHEBUST=0
```

to invalidate the [build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) from hereon.

However, instead of passing a date or some other random value, I call

```sh
docker build --build-arg CACHEBUST=`git rev-parse ${GITHUB_REF}` ...
```

where `GITHUB_REF` is a branch name (e.g. `main`) whose latest commit hash is used. That means that docker’s build cache is being invalidated only if the branch from which I build the image has had commits since the last run of `docker build`.

Answer (score 11):

As of February 2016 it is not possible.

The feature has been requested at [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996)

Answer (score 9):

Not directly but you can divide your Dockerfile in several parts, build an image, then  FROM thisimage at the beginning of the next Dockerfile, and build the image with or without caching

Comment: Will this enable updating the commited layers in the base docker image?

Answer (score 7):

the feature added a week ago.

```
ARG FOO=bar

FROM something
RUN echo "this won't be affected if the value of FOO changes"
ARG FOO
RUN echo "this step will be executed again if the value of FOO changes"

FROM something-else
RUN echo "this won't be affected because this stage doesn't use the FOO build-arg"
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996#issuecomment-550020843

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this is a slight improvement on @steve's answer, above:

```
RUN git clone https://sdk.ghwl;erjnv;wekrv;qlk@gitlab.com/your_name/your_repository.git

WORKDIR your_repository

# Calls for a random number to break the cahing of the git clone
# (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134713/disable-cache-for-specific-run-commands/58801213#58801213)
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
RUN git pull
```

This uses the Docker cache of the git clone, but then runs an uncached update of the repository.

It *appears* to work, and it is faster - but many thanks to @steve for providing the underlying principles.

Comment: Nice. Keep in mind this breaks when there are rewrites

Answer (score -6):

Another quick hack is to write some random bytes before your command

```
RUN head -c 5 /dev/random > random_bytes && <run your command>
```

writes out 5 random bytes which will force a cache miss

Comment: The result of writing those random bytes gets cached as well, so if no files have changed before that command, it won't run the command again. This doesn't solve anything.