# Dockerfile to not cache specific RUN step

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am wondering how to specify which step to not cache within the `Dockerfile`?

In this example, I want to cache `npm install` but I do not want to cache `newman run`. Can I do this within this `Dockerfile`?

```
FROM postman/newman
RUN npm install -g newman-reporter-teamcity
COPY . /etc/newman

# Do not cache
RUN newman run collections.json -x --delay-request 10 -r teamcity
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable cache for specific RUN commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134713/disable-cache-for-specific-run-commands)

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica - I saw that post but it isn't what I'm looking for. The responses revolve around either passing in a random argument to invalidate the cache (which from my understanding will not solve my issue), or to break the Dockerfile up into several files (which I am trying to keep in one piece).

Comment: Why won't the random argument solve your issue?

Comment: There's also this question, with the same answers: [rebuild docker image from specific step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35154219/596285)

Comment: That seems like you want it to be the `CMD` of the image and not something you `RUN` at build time.  (I'd be surprised if you wanted the test results permanently embedded in the image.)