# How to start docker build at a certain stage in a multi-stage build?

Tags: docker

Our application take a very long time to compile.  Any change to the Dockerfile triggers a full-recomplile (which takes a very long time)  The Dockerfile is a muli-stage build. I'm trying to work on the second stage.  Is there any way to tell `docker build` to begin at the second stage?

```
FROM debian:latest AS builder

# 10-20 mins worth of stuff here

FROM alpine:latest AS runner
WORKDIR /

COPY --from=builder /work/myapp.zip .
RUN unzip myapp.zip -d /myapp

# and more stuff that I'm working on here
```

Is there some way to do `docker build --begin-with runner`?

Comment: When it `COPY --from=builder`, where is it supposed to start, if it hasn't built the source image already?  (You might try to adjust the `COPY` lines in the first stage so changing the Dockerfile doesn't automatically result in a full recompile.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--target [STAGE-NAME]` from the build command according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options), e.g

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --target runner -t imagename:1.0 .
```

This will compile just the runner stage

Answer (score 0):

Docker build run from the last *changed* stage..

See here might help you
[rebuild docker image from specific step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154219/rebuild-docker-image-from-specific-step)

Comment: I don't see how this is starting from a certain line.  Despite the title of that article, it looks like it's talking about cache-busting (forcing a total rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Docker build cache should handle such situations automatically.
However this implementation has it's limits. It may not give you exactly what you want, but may be close.

Check out https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-build-cache