# How to force Docker for a clean build of an image

Tags: docker

I have build a Docker image from a Docker file using the below command.

```
$ docker build -t u12_core -f u12_core .
```

When I am trying to rebuild it with the same command, it's using the build cache like:

```
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:12.04
 ---> eb965dfb09d2
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Pavan Gupta <pavan.gupta@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4354ccf9dcd8
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bcbca2fcf204
Step 4 : RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 103f1a261d44
Step 5 : RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dde41f8d0904
Step 6 : RUN apt-get install -y git-core
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9be002f08b6a
Step 7 : RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a752fd73a698
Step 8 : RUN apt-get install -y logrotate
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93bca09b509d
Step 9 : RUN apt-get install -y lsb-release
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd4d10cf18bc
Step 10 : RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 63b4ecc39ff0
Step 11 : RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9532e31518a6
Step 12 : RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 47d1660bd544
Step 13 : RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1f97f1c52f7
Step 14 : RUN wget -O aerospike.tgz 'http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd7dde7a98b9
Step 15 : RUN tar -xvf aerospike.tgz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54adaa09921f
Step 16 : RUN dpkg -i aerospike-server-community-*/*.deb
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 11aba013eea5
Step 17 : EXPOSE 22 3000 3001 3002 3003
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e33aaa78a931
Step 18 : CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25f5fe70fa84
Successfully built 25f5fe70fa84
```

The cache shows that aerospike is installed. However, I don't find it inside containers spawn from this image, so I want to rebuild this image without using the cache. How can I force Docker to rebuild a clean image without the cache?

Comment: As an aside, you should generally try to minimize the number of `RUN` directives.

Comment: @Ya. It used to be that Docker always created a separate layer for each `RUN` directive, so a `Dockerfile` with many `RUN` directives would consume ginormous amounts of disk space; but this has apparently been improved somewhat in recent versions.

Comment: When I try `docker-compose up -d`, where can I use `--no-cache`?

Comment: @O.o that's not possible. You first have to do `docker-compose build --no-cache` and then `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: At the end of the day, I was being dumb with the `--volume` option. I was using the wrong path the entire time, thinking the old one was being cached

Answer (score 2607, accepted):

There's a `--no-cache` option:

```
docker build --no-cache -t u12_core -f u12_core .
```

In older versions of Docker you needed to pass `--no-cache=true`, but this is no longer the case.

Comment: Also note that `--no-cache` works with `docker-compose build`.

Comment: You might also want to use `--pull`. This will tell docker to get the latest version of the base image. This is necessary in addition to `--no-cache` if you already have the base image (ex: `ubuntu/latest`) and the base image has been updated since you last pulled it. See the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options).

Comment: @CollinKrawll: The `--pull` option did the trick for me. Just `--no-cache`, build still broke. Put in `--pull` as well, build worked! Thank you!

Comment: If someone is calling docker build isn't it assumed that they want to rebuild without the cache? In what use case would someone want to build an image and use a previously built image? <rant> I just lost a day because an earlier build failed silently yet completed "successful" and I was using the broken image not understanding why updates to the build script wasnt working </rant>

Comment: @Jeff When you're developing a docker image, docker build will only redo layers/steps that have been modified. If I have five steps, and I add a new step at index 3, the layers associated with step 1 and 2 can be re-used. This greatly speeds up the development process

Comment: @Jeff I've had to build images that take 2h to build completely. The cache is pretty useful in those cases. If used effectively, it'll save a lot of time. It's pretty common to structure the docker images to take full advantage of this.

Comment: @Ivan Its not speeding up my build process because it won't build. ><

Answer (score 257):

In some extreme cases, your only way around recurring build failures is by running:

```
docker system prune
```

The command will ask you for your confirmation:

```
WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all volumes not used by at least one container
    - all networks not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

This is of course not a direct answer to the question, but might save some lives... It did save mine.

Comment: adding -a -f makes it better

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Works for me, `Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4`

Comment: @PerLundberg, I updated `docker` to the same version and it works, thank you.

Comment: This is way overkill for this scenario and not a usable answer if you do not want to delete everything.

Comment: This will even delete the images of stopped containers, probably something you do not want. Recent versions of docker have the command `docker builder prune` to clear the cached build layers. Just fell into the trap after blindly copying commands from stack overflow.

Comment: This doesn't even work as a solution to the problem.

Comment: I do this: `docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker builder prune -af && docker image prune -af && docker system prune -af` . It's ridiculous that there's no 1 docker command for doing all of this (stop all containers and clear all cache!).

Answer (score 204):

To ensure that your build is completely rebuild, including checking the base image for updates, use the following options when building:

`--no-cache` - This will force rebuilding of layers already available

`--pull` - This will trigger a pull of the base image referenced using FROM ensuring you got the latest version.

The full command will therefore look like this:

```
docker build --pull --no-cache --tag myimage:version .
```

Same options are available for docker-compose:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache --pull
```

**Note** that if your docker-compose file references an image, the --pull option will not actually pull the image if there is one already.

To force docker-compose to re-pull this, you can run:

```
docker-compose pull
```

Comment: Curiously this didn't work for me!

Comment: I had to go via https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801213/1021819

Answer (score 80):

The command `docker build --no-cache .` solved our similar problem.

Our Dockerfile was:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install php5-fpm
```

But should have been:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install php5-fpm
```

To prevent caching the update and install separately.

See: *[Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)*

Comment: The "should have been" is misleading. If Docker sees that it has a cached copy of `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install php5-fpm` you would still see it get reused with the old contents.

Comment: Actually it still makes sense to join them, because otherwise if you change the installation line, it will still use the old package cache, which will often have problems if the cache is out of date (usually, files will 404.)

Comment: But should have been:


    `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install php5-fpm && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`


In fact, is best practice to cleanup the apt/lists files before the "closing" of the RUN

Answer (score 66):

Most of information here are correct.
Here a compilation of them and my way of using them.

The idea is to stick to the recommended approach (build specific and no impact on other stored docker objects) and to try the more radical approach (not build specific and with impact on other stored docker objects) when it is not enough.

**Recommended approach :**

1) Force the execution of each step/instruction in the Dockerfile :

```
docker build --no-cache
```

or with `docker-compose build` :

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

We could also combine that to the `up` sub-command that recreate all containers:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache &&
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

These way don't use cache but for the docker builder and the base image referenced with the `FROM` instruction.

2) Wipe the docker builder cache (if we use Buildkit we very probably need that) :

```
docker builder prune -af
```

3) If we don't want to use the cache of the parent images, we may try to delete them such as :

```
docker image rm -f fooParentImage
```

In most of cases, these 3 things are perfectly enough to allow a clean build of our image.
So we should try to stick to that.

**More radical approach :**

In corner cases where it seems that some objects in the docker cache are still used during the build and that looks repeatable, we should try to understand the cause to be able to wipe the missing part very specifically.
If we really don't find a way to rebuild from scratch, there are other ways but it is important to remember that these generally delete much more than it is required. So we should use them with cautious overall when we are not in a local/dev environment.

1) Remove all images without at least one container associated to them  :

```
docker image prune -a
```

2) Remove many more things :

```
docker system prune -a
```

That says :

```
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache
```

Using that super delete command may not be enough because it strongly depends on the state of containers (running or not). 
When that command is not enough, I try to think carefully which docker containers could cause side effects to our docker build and to allow these containers to be exited in order to allow them to be removed with the command.

Comment: docker image prune (without -a) is friendlier and won't nuke all your images you might want.

Comment: Any ideas why I am in an edge case? :( Can give more details as required - but under what circumstances could they occur?

Comment: I had to go via https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801213/1021819

Answer (score 39):

With docker-compose try `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate`

Comment: ( `docker-compose pull`  or  `--pull`is necessary to get the base image updated before )

Comment: What is the equivalent of this code with a single container Dockerfile?

Answer (score 17):

I would not recommend using `--no-cache` in your case.

You are running a couple of installations from step 3 to 9 (I would, by the way, prefer using a one liner) and if you don't want the overhead of re-running these steps each time you are building your image you can modify your `Dockerfile` with a temporary step prior to your `wget` instruction.

I use to do something like `RUN ls .` and change it to `RUN ls ./` then `RUN ls ./.` and so on for each modification done on the tarball retrieved by `wget`

You can of course do something like `RUN echo 'test1' > test && rm test` increasing the number in `'test1` for each iteration.

It looks dirty, but as far as I know it's the most efficient way to continue benefiting from the cache system of Docker, which saves time when you have many layers...

Comment: The ability to be able to not use the cache after a certain point is a feature requested by many (see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996 for alternatives for cache busting)

Comment: I had to go via https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801213/1021819

Answer (score 11):

sometimes `docker build --no-cache` and even removing all containers and images on the system does not clear all docker stuffs , in such case you should use `docker system prune` , to remove all unused containers, networks, images, and volumes. This will remove all cached data, including any dangling images or containers.
so to achieve a force fresh build run this commands:

```
//remove all containers
1- docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) 

//remove all images
2- docker image rm $(docker images -q)  

/remove all unused containers, networks, images, and volumes
3- docker system prune  /
```

so now anything related to the docker is gone and docker cache is completely deleted , like you have a fresh docker installation .

Answer (score 5):

You can manage the builder cache with `docker builder`

To clean all the cache with no prompt:
`docker builder prune -af`

Comment: OP is not using buildkit

Answer (score -1):

**GUI-driven approach:** Open the docker desktop tool (that usually comes with Docker):

1. under "Containers / Apps" stop all running instances of that image
2. under "Images" remove the build image (hover over the box name to get a context menu), eventually also the underlying base image