# Alembic revision autogenerate wrong configuration read

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, alembic

I'm trying to run alembic revision --autogenerate. But when trying to run its trying to connect to an IP that I previously setup. Right now I updated the alembic.ini to have the latest IP of my mysql container. But when running alembic revision its still connecting or using the old IP address and not the new one. I tried stopping and running the app again for a new build but still the same. Any fix or workaround on this?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: I'm new to docker but see the answer I posted hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's a --no-cache option.

docker build --no-cache -t u12_core -f u12_core .

Edit: In older versions of Docker you needed to pass --no-cache=true, but this is no longer the case.

For more information see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35594987)