# Removed Docker image is reappearing again upon new build command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Scenario:**
I made a working `dockerfile`, and I want to test them from scratch. However, the remove command only removes the image temporarily, meaning that running build command again will make them reappear as if it was never removed in a first place.

**Example:**

This is what my terminal looks like:
[image]

**Note: first two images are irrelevant to this question.*

The `***_seis` image is removed using `docker rmi ***_seis` command, and as a result, running `docker images` will show that `***_seis` image was deleted.

However, when I run the following build command:

```bash
docker build -f dockerfile -t ***_seis:latest .
```

It will build successfully, but gives this result:
[image]

Even though it was removed seconds ago, build took less than a minute and the created date indicates that it was made 3 days ago.

**Log:**

This is what my build log looks like:

```
docker build -f dockerfile -t ***_seis:latest .
[+] Building 11.3s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jupyter/base-notebook:latest                                                                                                       11.2s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/jupyter/base-notebook:latest@sha256:bc9ad73498f21ae716ba0e58d660063eae1677f6dd2bd5b669248fd0bf22dc79                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 32B                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [2/9] RUN apt update &&     apt install --no-install-recommends -y         software-properties-common         git         zip         unzip         wget         v  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] RUN conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions jupyter_nbextensions_configurator jupyter-resource-usage                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [4/9] RUN mkdir /home/jovyan/environment_ymls                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [5/9] COPY seis.yml /home/jovyan/environment_ymls/seis.yml                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [6/9] RUN conda env create -f /home/jovyan/environment_ymls/seis.yml                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [7/9] RUN python -m ipykernel install --name seis--display-name "seis"                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [8/9] WORKDIR /home/jovyan/***_seis                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [9/9] RUN chown -R jovyan:users /home/jovyan                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:16a8e90e47c0adc1c32f28e32ad17a8bc72795c3ca9fc39e792fa383793c3bdb                                                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/***_seis:latest
```

**Troubleshooting:** So far, I've tried different ways of removing them, such as

```
docker rmi <image_name>
docker image prune
```

and manually removing from docker desktop.

I made sure that all containers are deleted by using:

```
docker ps -a
```

**Expected result:** If successful, it should rebuild from scratch, takes longer than a minute to build, and creation date should reflect the time it was actually created.

**Question:**
I would like to know what is the issue here in terms of image not being deleted completely. Why does it recreate image from the past rather than just starting new build?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Docker for a clean build of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594987/how-to-force-docker-for-a-clean-build-of-an-image)

Comment: You can always nuke the image cache and all the other generated resources with `docker system prune`. Remove all containers, images, volumes and network configs. It will make Docker feel like you've done a fresh install.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne yes, I think that's what was aiming for. Thank you for the suggestion.

Normally, I would take the nuclear option, but I had other images that I wanted to preserve, hence the `--no-cache` option is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's building from the cache. Since no inputs appear to have changed to the build engine, and it has the steps from the previous build, they are reused, including the image creation date.

You can delete the build cache. But I'd recommend instead to run:

```
docker build --pull --no-cache -f dockerfile -t ***_seis:latest .
```

The `--pull` option pulls a new base image should you have an old version pulled locally. And the `--no-cache` option skips the caching for various steps (in particular a RUN step that may fetch the latest external dependency).