# Docker RUN ls shows cached files

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to setup a docker container and am using `RUN ls` to help debug. However, when I run `RUN ls`, docker prints out the following:

```
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96223b1b0748
```

I am expecting it to log out files in the folder. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Here is my full Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest 

WORKDIR /app

COPY app .

RUN ls
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you `docker build` or `docker build --no-cache`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable cache for specific RUN commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134713/disable-cache-for-specific-run-commands)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker caches recently built layers so that subsequent builds can reuse them.

The simplest way to break this behavior is to use the `--no-cache` flag during build:

```
docker build --no-cache ...
```

However this will invalidate all cached layers. If you still want to use cached layers for layers before the `RUN ls` instruction, you can put the following line before it:

```
ARG CACHE_TS=default_ts
```

And then gives this argument a new value on every new build:

```
docker build --build-arg CACHE_TS=$(date +%s) ...
```

Please see this Github issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22832