# How to avoid the Docker build cache for a single command/RUN?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using `RUN ls /some/directory` for "printf-debugging" of a `Dockerfile`. After the command has been run once and no command has changed before, the result is cached and no output is provided.

I can change the command with a part which is never executed, e.g. append `|| echo some changing number]` which is annoying for every run or turn off the build cache which affects more `RUN`s than necessary and thus slows down the development of the `Dockerfile`.

Is there a way to disable the cache for just one `RUN` without any of the described downsides?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134713/disable-cache-for-specific-run-commands

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Thanks for this better duplicate. I flagged the question I choose as identical to mine as duplicate of the question you linked. I also added comments to the moby issues linked in different answers which seem to be be duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Would using a build arg be an acceptable solution?

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine
RUN echo "executed 1"

# Above this will be cached, below will be retriggered with new builds
ARG BUILD

RUN echo "executed 2"
```

Then, running with different build arg number to re-run everything below the ARG

```
$ docker build --build-arg BUILD=2 -t temp .
```

Or, with using `date` as the build number:

```
$ docker build --build-arg BUILD="$(date)" -t temp .
```