# Run npm update in docker without using the cache on that specific update

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-package

**Background:**

1. I'm writing code in `node.js`, using `npm` and `docker`. I'm trying to get my docker file to use cache when I build it so it doesn't take too long.
2. We have a "common" repo that we use to keep logic that is used in a variety of repositories and this gets propagated is npm packages.

**The problem:**

I want the docker file NOT use the cache on my "common" package.

Docker file:

```
FROM node:12-alpine as X

RUN npm i npm@latest -g
RUN mkdir /app && chown node:node /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ tini \
    && apk add --update tzdata

USER node
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean --force
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . .
```

package.json has this line:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@myorg/myorg-common-repo": "~1.0.13",
```

I have tried adding these lines in a variety of places and nothing seems to work:

1. RUN npm uninstall @myorg/myorg-common-repo && npm install @myorg/myorg-common-repo
2. RUN npm update @myorg/myorg-common-repo --force

Any ideas on how I can get docker to build and not use the cache on `@myorg/myorg-common-repo` ?

Comment: When you change the version number of the dependent library in the `package-lock.json` file, that will invalidate the Docker cache and re-run the `npm install` sequence.  (Even if it's "shared code" that you wrote, treat it as a library and use proper semantic versioning for it.)

Comment: @DavidMaze - unfortunately, this did not help. I already had my `package.json` set as described above, and the `docker-compose` command used the cache without checking if there is a newer version for `myorg-common-repo`

Comment: Did the version number in `package-lock.json` change?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I'm not sure if you're asking whether I changed it or it got changed during the process, but in any case, it was not changed. If you suggestion is that I change it manually - that is not what I'm looking for since I could also just change the `package.json` file itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally managed to solve this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772666/3045171):

What we want to do is invalidate the cache for a specific block in the Docker file and then run our update command. This is done by adding a build argument to the command (CLI or Makefile) like so:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build --build-arg CACHEBUST=0
```

And then Adding this **additional** block to the Docker file:

```
ARG CACHEBUST=1 
USER node
RUN npm update @myorg/myorg-common-repo
```

This does what we want.
The `ARG CACHEBUST=1` invalidates the cache and the `npm update` command runs without it.

Comment: this does not work for me. Does this only work using docker-compose?

Comment: @TorstenN. - I used this as part of docker-build